# Microsoft Excel pivot table with more than one filterable item/value per row

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in Excel with the header column "system boundary" and various row items below. Usually, Excel will enable me to filter a column for each individual row item.
However, I am wondering whether it also possible to have more than one filterable item per cell? E.g. filtering for `cradle to cradle` will also display all rows in which `cradle to cradle` plus an additional string e.g. `Cradle to cradle, Gate to gate`.

```
| System boundary                |
|--------------------------------|
| Cradle to cradle               |
| Cradle to gate                 |
| Cradle to cradle, Gate to gate |
| Gate to gate                   |
| Gate to gate, cradle to cradle |
| Gate to gate                   |
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a Slicer to the Pivot Table
The quickest way to see a list of the Multiple Items in the filter is to add a slicer to the pivot table.

Select any cell in the pivot table.
Select the Analyze/Options tab in the ribbon.
Click the Insert Slicer button.
Check the box for the field that is in the Filters area with the filter applied to it.
Press OK.

A slicer will be added to the worksheet.  The items that are selected in the filter drop-down list will also be selected/highlighted in the slicer.  These two controls work interchangeably, and we can use both the slicer and the filter drop-down menu to apply filters to the pivot table.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This does not yet allow me to save several filterable criteria within one cell though.